# How can I run flutter unit test in the browser?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, flutter-web, flutter-test

The command `flutter test -p chrome /path/to/my/test/file.dart` unable to work. What parameters should I use?

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1817], locale zh-CN)
    • Flutter version 2.0.3 at D:\SDK\Flutter
    • Framework revision 4d7946a68d (13 days ago), 2021-03-18 17:24:33 -0700
    • Engine revision 3459eb2436
    • Dart version 2.12.2
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn
```

Comment: What you attached is the output of flutter doctor.
What is the error that you get when you run `flutter test -p chrome...`?

Answer (score 0):

Being a unit test you should not specify any platform. So the command should only be `flutter test /path/to/my/test/file.dart`
You only need to run on a specific platform in cases of integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

If u using VScode Follow this steps
1.Step 1 area click anf then
2.Step 2 area Whatever device you want to choose

[[image: STEPS]][]